# Sending an UDP broadcast via socket raises exception constantly

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

All I need to do is sending out a broadcast message with an ASCII encoded command and wait for an answer.

I've found numerous tutorials on how to do this and nearly figured everything out. I studied the MSDN articles about sockets and it's `SendTo` method but whatever I do or try it raises this exception at my `SendTo` call:

> **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException**: 'The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced'

The provided error code is [**10045**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2). Not very detailed as so often in low level APIs.

I assume it should be correct. I bind to my Ethernet adapter (the one hooked up to the intranet where my device I'm trying to contact resides) on any available port and broadcast to that port I am looking for.

That's my code so far:

```
byte[] encoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cast);

Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,
    ProtocolType.Udp);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontRoute, 1);
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.10.87"), 0));

IPEndPoint broadcastPartner = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 32001);
int sent = socket.SendTo(encoded, SocketFlags.Broadcast, broadcastPartner);

Console.WriteLine($"Sent {sent} bytes.");


SpinWait wait = new SpinWait();
while (true)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int read = 0;
    try
    {
        read = socket.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.Broadcast);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        wait.SpinOnce();
        continue;
    }

    if (read == 0) continue;

    Console.WriteLine("Received message: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
}
```

Comment: I tried using `UdpClient` which does send something (at least the call returns the correct amount of bytes and throws no exception) but Wireshark is telling me that ICMP signalled _Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)_ on that package. In depth it tells that the IPv4 protocol has an issue with the length (123 bytes): _Expert Info (Error/Protocol): IPv4 total length exceeds packet length (103 bytes)_. As far as I know and found out, the UDP package size caps at ~`short.MaxValue` which I am far away from ...

Comment: My 2 cents, from the error it _seems_ you are using unsupported combination of parameters/options. But I could be wrong!

Comment: Update! your code sample works by removing the redundant `SocketFlags.Broadcast` from `int sent = socket.SendTo(encoded, broadcastPartner);`. But I've not tested if it indeed broadcasts.

Comment: I eventually got it working by using `new UpdClient(32004)` (specifiying the listening port but **not** an IP got it working. I always tried with IP and didn't see the port-only overload. With IP it always crashed unexpectedly. The UdpClient somehow manages to send a broadcast without crash unlike the socket. Receiving didn't work (even using `IP.Broadcast` and the port) unless I specified the port in the constructor. Still, I'm a bit confused why this won't work with sockets and why it crashes. I don't see any wrong parameters / options...